# Deferring Callback until setTimeout has Completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have searched everywhere for a solution to this but have not been able to find anything thus far *(I am probably using the wrong keywords! If this is a duplicate, please point out and I will delete)*.

Could one of you brilliant SO geniuses kindly explain to me why the following does not work as one would hope? What I mean by this is the `complete` callback is called before the `setTimeout` has completed within the `success` callback and I don't quite understand why.

```
$.ajax({
    url: options.url,
    data: options.data,
    success: function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('firing');
        },2000);
    },
    dataType: options.dataType,
    complete: function(){
        console.log('ended');   
    }
});
```

Is it because a new thread has been started by the `setTimeout` within the `success` callback?

Is this possible to achieve without passing in a callback function into the `success` callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because `setTimeout()` does not block the execution of code.

Therefore the `complete` callback fires at the same moment as it would without your call to `setTimeout()`.

You will have to put your `console.log('ended');` call into a timeout (too) or call your complete handler inside the timeout. :)

Comment: That was quick +1, and exactly as I suspected! :-( If there wasn't a timeout within the callback, but instead a lot of code that took maybe 200ms to complete, would this defer the `complete` callback? In other words, does this not work simply because I am using `setTimeout`?

Comment: I must've misread before.. of course without the timeout complete would only be triggered after success spawns its "i am done" event. I believe you can solve your problem easily if you start thinking in terms of events. ;) simply define and trigger your own ones.

Comment: The `complete` callback is meant to be called once the `success` callback has completed! So how come this would not work?

Comment: It doesn't because complete has no idea about his setTimeout(). and it finishes after success is done setting up the timeout.

Comment: Ignore the `setTimeout`, I only put it there for testing, if there was a lot of code within the `success` callback, and this code took, for sake of argument, 200ms to complete, would this defer the `complete` callback by 200ms?

Comment: If you read the manual that is what it says: complete
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )
A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). ..... This is an Ajax Event.

Comment: I did of course read the manual, was just confused as to what you said. Makes sense now, thanks for your help :-)